# Can't proove that a function is convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I'm trying to proove that a couple of functions are convex but one of them is giving me a hard time. Here it comes : [image: function]

I can't see how this function can be written as the $\max$ or $\sup$ of some family of functions so that I can use the hint. Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you could express $f(X,y)$ in terms of the dual of $x \mapsto x^T X x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $y^T X^{-1} y = 2 \sup_x ( y^T x - {1 \over 2} x^T X x ) $.

Note that for a fixed $x$, the function $(y,X) \mapsto y^T x - {1 \over 2} x^T X x$ is
linear, hence convex.

Hence the function $(y,X) \mapsto y^T X^{-1} y$ is convex.

Comment: Indeed, it solves the puzzle ! Could please elaborate more on the intuition that leads to the result ? How did you come to think about that function ? Thanks.

Comment: @MhamedJabri: Old age :-). I've seen it before. Look at the convex conjugate/Fenchel dual.